# Force selection of full elements

Tags: javascript, css, selection

When making a hex viewer, it does not make sense to let the user select a half of a byte, so I'm trying to force the selection to snap to byte boundaries.

In CSS, I could set `user-select` to `all`, but that makes it very difficult to select more than one byte, because clicking inside the element and moving your mouse starts a drag operation instead of selection.

I could try doing it via JS, but all of selection API seems to be marked as experimental technology, and its behavior differs across browsers. I.e. trying to use `addRange` to extend range in Chrome does nothing, and prints a warning in console linking to [this document](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6680566019653632).

Is there a reliable way to do this in CSS/JS?

Comment: Can you use a `<textarea>`? Also please provide an example of what you are talking about.

Comment: Why not have bytes as individual elements and create an click listener to get the clicked byte's text value?

Comment: Is something like this useful? http://jsfiddle.net/dfbzLq73/

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir that looks cool for textareas, but I have bytes as individual elements (so I can add visual gaps between them without changing contents) and having thousands of textareas is probably more taxing on performance than thousands of spans. Although it looks like I will have to switch to canvas anyway, because viewing more than ~10K worth of data kills the browser (virtual scrolling would also work, but it's a HUGE pain to get selection to work in those).

Comment: Not sure if I need to provide an example for when it's just a bunch of spans with 2 characters each.

Comment: @riv Ah, I see! Good luck then! ;-)